# Refer root site collection master page on other site collection pages

Tags: custom-masterpage, root, asp

I want to refer master page of my root site collection on other site collections

Site Collection A : https://www.siteA.com/

Site Collection B : https://www.siteA.com/sites/siteB/, from this site collection I need to access master page of Site Collection A.

Below is the page directive in one of the pages in site collection B (in Pages folder) by which I am trying to access master page of site collection A.

"<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/sitea.master" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>"

But this page directive refers to master page on site collection B instead of A. Please let me know how can I successfully access root site collection master page on one of the other site collections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try specifying the URL to the master page A? `MasterPageFile="/sites/SiteA/_catalogs/masterpage/sitea.master"` ?

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: I was expecting it, but didn't try. This should be normal. We have to to copy the master page to all site collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. It doesn't work that way.  If everyone could do that, they would do it.